# Why "grails assemble" and "gradle assemble" produces different WAR archive

Tags: gradle, grails, war

In Grails 3 the command `grails assemble` produces WAR archive without several JARs in comparison to `gradle assemble`:

[image]

Why is there this difference and what causes it ?

I have tested it on plain Grails 3.3.9 project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is caused by setting `grails.env` to `production` in grails [assemble command](https://github.com/grails-profiles/base/blob/master/commands/assemble.groovy#L9)

So the following commands produces the same WAR archive:

- `grails war`
- `grails assemble`
- `gradle assemble -Dgrails.env=production`